# Nuxt module that adds another website as serverMiddleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, nuxt.js

## The idea

First you have a main Nuxt website like any other. Then you add my module to your project. My module then adds a subdomain "admin.example.com" to your project which is a fully fleshed out Nuxt based website all of its own but running from your projects process, so instead of making two website projects that have to be started separately the idea is that I can make my one website project and then one module project which adds the other website, turning three projects into two.

## Code

module.js

```
this.addServerMiddleware(vhost('admin.website.com', adminApp));
```

adminApp.js

```
const {Nuxt, Builder} = require('nuxt');

const config = require('../admin/nuxt.config');
config.dev = true;

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

if (nuxt.options.dev) {
  new Builder(nuxt).build()
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
}

module.exports = nuxt.render;
```

Part of nuxt.config.js from the admin website

```
// __dirname leads to my modules directory
// process.cwd() leads to the main websites folder
module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',
  srcDir: __dirname,
  rootDir: __dirname,
  modulesDir: process.cwd(),
```

## The problem

Whenever I go to "admin.website.com" it results in the following message:

[image]

I've tried tonnes various changes and tweaks already but nothing seems to be working. As far as I can tell it might have to do with the fact that either A) the website gets built somewhere it doesn't find the generated resource files, or B) that I haven't prayed enough to the spaghetti monster.

I've tried exporting `adminApp` as an Express app that uses `app.use(nuxt.render)` but that results in the same error so I'm certain that's not the issue. I've tried using an Express app for `api.website.com` and that works just fine, so I know I'm like THIS |--| close to making this all work. Adding subdomains like this does work and each subdomain can be an Express app, but for some reason Nuxt can't find any resources when used this way. According to https://nuxtjs.org/api/nuxt-render/ `nuxt.render(req, res)` as you can see takes `req` and `res` as arguments, which should mean I don't need to use it via an Express app, `serverMiddleware` is already an Express app.

Thoughts?

Comment: For now I'm using `nuxt generate` on the admin site and serving it using a regular Express app by simply using `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../admin/dist' + req.path + '/index.html'));`, just putting it out there if anyone wants a tip for a workaround, I still want to fix this without the need for building the site and serving a static website.

Comment: Actually turned out to be easier to just use `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/../admin/dist')));` as a workaround. Still not happy though.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in this error before when serving apps through serverless. I think that you need to explicitly set a publicPath or a buildDir in nuxt.config.js for both apps to make setup work. Your problem could be that all the build assets are generated in the same folder, causing one of the apps to not find the build assets. The buildDir property is set on the nuxt.config.js and the publicPath setting is defined on the build property.

More info here:

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-builddir

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#publicpath

Comment: Unfortunately, neither property changed anything. After some digging, `publicPath` is only applied for `spa` version, the issue is that I can't get `universal` to work, so `publicPath` isn't applicable. And `buildDir` I've tried before but it didn't change anything then either, and shouldn't, since the modules website is built inside the websites directory in its own `.nuxt` directory, all `buildDir` accomplishes then is an altered folder name. The main website works just fine I might add, it's only the modules subdomained website that can't find its resources.